# Preventing uninstall xml file database

Tags: android, xml, delphi, delete-file, delphi-xe5

I'm testing Delphi XE5 iOS and Android, create a form to users login with 2 fields and store that information in `users.xml`.

But when I re-compile the pack, the IDE uninstall my application and the file logins.xml is deleted because the uninstaller remove the file.

My idea is when create `users.xml`, create in a SDCard, because after I need to transfer this XML file to other phone, and I need only to share SDCard in other smathphone...

Maybe using `TPath.GetDocumentsPath`, but how I can "see" the file in fileexplorer like *Astro File Manager?*

Is anyway to prevent deleting file or create file in SDCard that could see in Any File Manager?